# I have the “edit questions and answers” privilege. Why do my edits still fail with “Suggested edit queue is full”?

Tags: support, bug

I have the [“edit questions and answers” privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), which says “we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through peer review”.

When I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219247/go-module-and-packages-import), I nonetheless got a “Suggested edit queue is full” error:
[image: Suggested edit queue is full]

Why does editing still depend on the state of the queue when the “edit” privilege allegedly bypasses the queue anyway?

Comment: So you say the *"Moderation privilege awarded at 2,000 reputation"* part doesn't apply to you? Employees in a collective have certain rights on collective articles, but this doesn't apply to normal Q&A. Those rights are earned the normal way, by reputation and tag score.

Comment: Oho! That would be the problem. The privileges that are presented as greyed-out in the UI are the ones I have, not the ones I lack. That's incredibly confusing.

Comment: @bcmills Those privileges sites usually tell you if have earned them. For example, look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user on the right sidebar, there it should say "You earned this privilege" with a green tick symbol. I guess that tag is missing for the edit privileges site?

Comment: It's there; I've just been conditioned to ignore the right sidebar entirely because it's usually so spammy. (The right sidebar on SO is usually where the promotions and ads go. Ad blindness is real!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was misled by a confusing UI — I don't actually have the indicated privilege yet.

The confusing elements are annotated in the screenshot below.

[image: annotated screenshot]

Comment: Please add exact details of the misleading information so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Added an annotated screenshot. Really this page needs UX attention, I think. (I'm not a UX designer — I can point out the problems, but I don't know how best to fix them.)

Comment: mmm, methinks it's just you who perceives it this way... It's the page that lists privileges *to earn*, not the earned ones. It makes sense to grey out the earned ones.

Comment: @bcmills Are you in a culture where a tick means "no"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton bcmills is probably in a culture where greyed out means "no", and a greyed tick means "the tick is not active yet", similar to answers on your questions, that have a tick when there are _not_ accepted, but the tick is greyed out (whereas the tick on the answer that you _did_ accept is bright green and shiny).

Comment: @Marijn and I assume they also live in a culture that equates *green* checkmarks with *gray* ones? It is very clear that's the item as a whole is grayed out, not the tick. Not to mention the numbers on the left not making *any* sense in this case.

Comment: @OlegValter the numbers are also confusing indeed, because nowhere in the UI is mentioned what the numbers represent. Reputation is mentioned a few times but the column with the numbers does not have a caption. For all you know it could be an indicator of importance or something, with the most important privileges earned first.

Comment: Sure, nowhere, except for the clear text on the same page: "Gain more privileges by increasing your reputation (points you receive from your fellow users for posting helpful questions and answers)." Does everything have to be *that* literal? Come on, that's just feigning ignorance because the traffic light did not have "stop" spelled out on it.

Comment: Andrew, I am in a culture where low-contrast elements are hard to notice compared to high-contrast ones. The presence of the ticks didn't really even register for me.

Comment: Usability is about how it *actually* works, with actual users with their actual skill level/experience in actual circumstances (say, under time contraints), not rationalising after the fact.